# Cómo saber qué registro está modificando otra aplicación en una base de datos en PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

Tengo una base de datos en PostgreSql 9.3 la cual contiene tres tablas sin vínculos entre ellas (como llaves foráneas). A esta base de datos se conectan dos aplicaciones en Java 8 que corren una en un cliente y otra en el servidor donde está la BD. La aplicación en el servidor necesita saber si se está modificando sólo una de las tablas de la BD.

Estuve jugando con el código de [esta web](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/listennotify.html),
y pude recibir notificaciones en mi aplicación de ejemplo, incluso enviándolas desde la ventana de scripts sql del pgAdmin III simplemente ejecutando "Notify mymessage" (en mi caso, funcionó sin necesidad de hacer "Select 1").

Lo bueno de este método es que bastaría que la aplicación cliente envíe notificaciones cada vez que modifica la tabla que le interesa a la aplicación en el servidor.

Lo malo de este método es que la aplicación en el servidor no sabe qué registro se está modificando, insertando o eliminando.

¿Hay alguna manera de enviar, junto a la notificación, datos como la clave primaria del registro involucrado?

Comment: Quizás más de los ya conocidos DML triggers? :). Una revisa aquí: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez tuve el mismo problema, la solución a la que llegue fue utilizar un trigger para INSERT y UPDATE que enviaba algo así:

```
PERFORM pg_notify('nombredetabla', NEW.campoidentificador);
```

Luego, escuchando el canal `nombredetabla`, recibía las notificaciones de los registros y mirando el payload sabia que registro fue actualizado.

Comment: por cierto, lo mismo funciona para DELETE pero hay que usar OLD en lugar de NEW

Comment: Tengan cuidado con la sentencia `PERFORM` que ignora las excepciones y condiciones de error que pueda lanzar la función llamada (en este caso `pg_notify`)

Answer (score 3):

for the completeness:

Se pueden enviar notificaciones con más información usando la instrucción de Postgres:

```
select pg_notify('canal_a_escuchar', 'cadena con datos');
```

La condición es que la app que recibe las notificaciones debe mantener una conexión abierta todo el tiempo:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
org.postgresql.PGConnection pgconn = (org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn;
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("LISTEN canal_a_escuchar");
stmt.close();
```

Y cada tanto debe pedir las notificaciones con:

```
pgconn.getNotifications();
```

Fuente: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/listennotify.html